# CS50 Problem set 2: readability.c help on implementing different functions

Tags: c, cs50

[Link to question.](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/)

I am new to implementing different functions other than main of course. I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do that because it is not working out for me.

This would be a rather easy solution to put everything into main but I avoided that due to the instructions hinting it's best to create separate functions and overall I think it's cleaner to have the main function just implement your various functions, right?

The problem I was having was getting the respective functions to be able to use other variables so I set some globals up. For some reason I also figured out I could not use a placeholder for the variable when I wanted to test if everything is working fine, instead I had to print the placeholder for the function itself, for e.g `printf("%d\n", letter_counter(text)` instead of `printf("%d\n", letter)`.

The issue I'm running into now is getting my coleman index function to work, I find that it is not able to print the S value but the L is working fine. Morover, if I call the the letter, word, & sentence function in main (which are commented out right now), this alters my results as well.

I am happy to receive other general pointers you might realize that needs some work. I think I'm just overall confused about getting different functions to work with one another.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int letter_counter(string text);
int word_counter(string text);
int sentence_counter(string text);
void coleman_liau_formula(string text);
int letter;
int spaces;
int sentences;

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    //letter_counter(text);
    //word_counter(text);
    //sentence_counter(text);
    coleman_liau_formula(text);

}

// letter counter
int letter_counter(string text)
{
    int i; //variable for looping through the string
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]) != 0)
        {
            letter++;
        }
    }
    return letter;
}

// word counter
int word_counter(string text)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (isspace(text[i]) != 0)
        {
            spaces++;
        }
    }
    if (letter == 0)
    {
        spaces = 0; // by default the program will output 1 word if no letters are inputted. this statement counters that.
        return spaces;
    }
    else
    {
        return spaces + 1;
    }
}

// sentence counter
int sentence_counter(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?') //one flaw is that an occurence such as ellipsis would increase the sentence counter
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}

void coleman_liau_formula(string text)
{
    //float L = ((float) letter_counter(text) / (float) word_counter(text)) * 100;
    //float S = ((float) sentence_counter(text) / (float) word_counter(text)) * 100;
    //int index = round((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);

    /*if (index >=16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }*/
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n", letter_counter(text), word_counter(text), sentence_counter(text));
}
```

Comment: There's a SE site specifically for CS50. Wouldn't it be better to post this there?

Comment: Yes, I posted there as well just in case, still new to this forum. Thanks.

Comment: Please always declare your cross-posting. Please link to your other question from here, and from here to your other question. This will allow readers to see if the question is already answered, and will show that you are keen not to waste the time of volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

The counter functions are cumulative. That is if `word_counter` is called 2 times, it will *double* the result. That should be all you need to know to make progress.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!